# Konsole hide tab bar

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde, konsole

Is it possible to hide konsole tab bar?  If so how. I've looked through the settings in the options panel for the profile, but nothing jumps out at me.  Does a command line setting exist, or configuration file modification help with this?  I use tmux so tabs are really useless to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is certainly possible on my system from:

```
Settings --> Configure Konsole --> Tab Bar --> Tab Bar Visibility
```

Screenshot of this setting with Tab Bar hidden:

[image]